# SocketException: Address already in use

Tags: .net, sockets, udp

I'm attempting to catch incoming UDP packets through an asynchronous socket listener

I'm using code from here: http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2004/12/26/receiving-udp-messages-using-udpclient-or-socket-classes.aspx

(I've also been reading through a very good tutorial here: http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/clientserversocketnetworkcommunication8d.html  that's not related to the question, just putting it up as a good resource)

However,  I get the following error:

```
SocketException: Address already in use
```

Here is the code:

```
private Byte[] buffer;

public void StartListening()
{
    int port = 6500; // 'netstat -an' shows this is initially unused
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Any; // IPAddress.Parse( "127.0.0.1" );
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    Socket sock = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    sock.Bind(ep); // 'SocketException: Address already in use'

    sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnReceive), sock);
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket s1 = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    int x = s1.EndReceive(ar);
    string message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, x);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    s1.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnReceive), s1);
}
```

Comment: The port is already in use.

Comment: @EJP, note: ''netstat -an' shows this is initially unused'

Comment: My bad, my script was getting run twice!  I will leave the question as the code is good and could help someone.

Comment: I was getting this exception because I made an incorrect assumption that the port had been closed as the socket went out of scope. Make sure you Close and Dispose the socket properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is actually correct.

The script was getting run twice.

Just providing this stub answer so the question doesn't misfile as unanswered.